# How to check the data written to EBS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS volume attached to an instance in AWS. I have noticed that there's a spike in the amount of data written to this volume every day at a specific time. The regularity of these write operations tells me that some update or something is pushed to this volume, since when I look at the CPU utilization for the same period there's is no jump. Does anyone know how can I find what data is being written at these specific intervals?

Comment: *"some update or something"* ... Nothing modifies data on, or writes to, EBS volumes other than the code running on your instance.  Writing to disk would not necessarily cause a notable CPU spike.  It has to be something on your instance.  What is the timing of the writes?

Comment: It's between 6:20 and 6:30 AM UTC

Comment: Take a look at the files in (I'm giving you this path from memory) `/etc/cron.d/cron.daily`.  These scripts run every day beginning after 06:00 UTC, iirc, due to the entry in `/etc/crontab`.